# How to get regular expression to stop at first occurrence and then start searching from there, leading to multiple results

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression to search for complete h1 tags (from start of `<h1>` to end of `</h1>`) in a content but it searches for the whole content

Regular expression

```
<h1.*<\/h1>
```

Content to search for

```
<h1 style=""></h1><span> alsjd alkj dalsd a</span><h1>asdsadsa</h1>
```

The result is one match only from first occurrence of starting h1 to last occurrence of ending h1. It matches the whole content.

I want it to give me 2 occurrence of starting and ending h1 tags
like the result should be

```
<h1 style=""></h1> and 
<h1>asdsadsa</h1>
```

Comment: You should specify the context, which parser are you using? From what you describe it seems the case of greedy matching (maximal munch), try `?` for lazy matching [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've to make `.*` non greedy

use this

```
<h1.*?<\/h1>
```